# Quantitative comparison for two matrice with different size

Tags: statistics

I am trying to determine whether 2 distinct groups exhibit similar trends over multiple quantitative traits.  I am looking for statistical measures to do this.

Basic setup:

```
Group 1: N1 members (e.g. each member is a species or gene)
Group 2: N2 members
For each members of group 1/2, I have M distinct measurement values (e.g. gene expression in a specific condition, height, weight)
N1 and N2 does not have to be equal
```

Starting data:

```
Matrix 1: A1 = N1 X M matrix (measurements for all members of Group 1)
Matrix 2: A2 = N2 X M matrix (measurements for all members of Group 2)
```

Objective: Quantify the similarity between Group 1 and Group 2

```
Looking for a symmetric measure "F" such that F(A1,A2)=F(A2,A1)="real number"
```

I know I can change the matrices A1 and A2 into probability distributions, and apply KL divergence, but KL divergence is not symmetric.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.